# what is/are the right WCF messaging function to use in my project?

Tags: wcf

I am novice in WCF and I have a project that needs to be migrated into WCF communication base with the client/server and server to server architecture.

My question is what is the right messaging function that I need for this project that insure the security of data across the network ,reliable connection and speed exchange of data.

I was able to find out the WCF has numerous messaging function.

Below is the architecture of my project:

[image]

**Note**: The clients should be simultaneously updated by both data processing and feed source servers. And clients also sends simultaneous requests to the servers while feeds are still being supplied by the feed source server.

I would be appreciate any suggestion or comments.

Comment: Any update on how you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

My first question is why are you putting the Connection Manager (CM) component in-between your clients and the services which they want to use? What is the job it does which means it needs to be right in the middle of everything?

This ultimately means that your CM component will have to handle potentially high volumes of bi-directional traffic across potentially different transport bindings and introduces a single failure point.

What if client A wants only to receive messages from the Feed Source (FS) component? Why should client A have to deal with an intermediary when it just wants to send a subscription notification to receive updates from the FS?

Equally, what if client B wants to send a message to the Data Processing (DP) component? Surely it should just be able to fire off a message to DP?

I think the majority of what you want to do with this architecture can be achieved with one-way messaging, in which case you should use netMsmqBinding (assuming you are in a pure wcf environment).

Comment: The CM (Connection Manager) manages all the connection and caches some information from the DP. This is to make sure that the whole system will scale in the environment where there will be thousands of clients involved. It also makes sure that the client will not directly connect to the DP Server directly. Moreover, the CM will be the one to connect the clients to both DP and FS. 

While the FS supplies continuous feeds, processing takes place at the same time. Clients are mandatory to receive feeds from FS and execute requests with DP at the same time.

Comment: Im actually considering to use duplex & callback in WCF, buy not yet final. Actually the flow is, once client(s) connect to the CM, the CM will provide passage to PD and FS. FS then, broadcast feeds to the connected client/s simultaneously. And the client can also send requests to DP while receiving the feeds. Moreover, DP also update client/s if there is/are a changes about the setting. Should I continue my plan of using Duplex and Callback under the WCF? (btw i am implementing NetTcpBinding)

Comment: Duplex WCF with callback is complex to understand and implement, and it does not scale (callbacks) or handle failure (no queuing) well. One way messaging is easy to understand and develop, it scales and is fault tolerant. Additionally I can't see why you need the CM component as all it's doing is caching common information. This functionality can be introduced on the service itself if you're worried about database contention or availability.